# garbage collection in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, garbage-collection, dispose

what to do when a stack frame is preventing a form from being garbage collected
in vb.net.

details :
I have created a form and call another form to be shown from the form.when the second form is shown the first is closed and disposed .But the first form is not being garbage collect. A stack frame is preventing it from being garbage collected what should I do

Comment: A stack frame, in and of itself, shouldn't prevent an object from being GCed, provided that you're running in release mode and all that's waiting to happen (when that frame is returned to) is for that method to immediately return. How did you determine that it was what was keeping the form object rooted?

Comment: i'm not exactly sure with what is release mode...but i m just running the exe ...the root path seems stack frame>application.threadcontext>form1.........for which even if i dispose or close the form it is not getting garbage collected

Comment: i tested it with .net memory profiler

Comment: There are two default configurations for any project, assuming you're working inside Visual Studio. There's a drop-down at the top that lets you select between "Debug" and "Release". In normal usage, your users should be running software that you compiled under the Release configuration, and in such a configuration, the form should be collectable.

Comment: And, (having seen your second comment), you should also make sure that you profile the Release configuration rather than the Debug one.

Comment: i m using the debug  mode....but what difference does that make in GC

Comment: Because in Debug mode, there's an expectation that you might set a breakpoint on that stack frame and inspect that object still - so it better not be GCed. Whereas in Release mode, there's no such expectation - so if there's no more code that's going to try to access that object (i.e. something that directly or indirectly calls `Me.`), then the object can be collected, *even if* some of the code for that object is still running (or in this case, waiting for a method to return before returning itself)

Comment: even in release mode it is behaving the same way so what can i do so that those objects are GCed when i close the form1

Comment: A "stack frame" could only ever keep a reference to a Form object when you use ShowDialog().  In which case it is very questionable to dispose the main form.  Pretty likely that you interpreting the output of your profiler wrong.  Or that you are micro-optimizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The garbage collector collects anything that's unreachable. So make sure that none of your code can reach the first form, and it will be collected eventually. Disposing is not the same thing as C's free().

One way you can get rid of your references in stack frames that cannot be closed is setting the reference to Nothing:

```
form1.Close()
form1 = Nothing
```